# Mock Service Worker doesn't intercept request

Tags: javascript, jestjs, msw, mswjs

app.js

```
class MyApp {
    async fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch('http://myurl.com', { method: 'GET' });

        console.log(response); // received: {}, expected: { val: true }
    }
}
export { MyApp };
```

app.test.js

```
import {MyApp} from "./app";
import {setupServer} from "msw/node";
import {rest} from "msw";

const server = setupServer(
    rest.get('http://myurl.com', (req, res, ctx) => res(ctx.json({ val: true })))
);

describe('App', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        server.listen();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        server.resetHandlers();
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        server.close();
    })

    it('should succeed', async () => {
        const myApp = new MyApp();

        await myApp.fetchData();
    });
});
```

I have simple project, almost empty with just few files. I had to polyfill the fetch so in my `setup-jest.js` file I have

```
global.fetch = () => Promise.resolve({});
```

Without that I'd get an error that the fetch is undefined. The problem is that inside `fetchData` method I get the polyfill value instead of {val: true} which I defined in test file inside setupServer. Why I'm not getting the expected value?

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.js']
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems working otherwise, but I suppose you shouldn't just replace the global `fetch` like that. Instead add`whatwg-fetch` as dev dependency and import it in your `setup-jest.js`. Hopefully that helps!